# compiling auto-talent plug-in on OSX

Tags: macos, makefile, audacity

I am trying to compile the auto-talent plug-in (http://tombaran.info/autotalent.html) to use as a LADSPA Audacity plug-in on Mac. I followed the directions correctly on linux but I was wondering how to build a version for Mac, if at all possible.

I downloaded the 0.2 source, and ran "make". however I get the following error:

```
gcc -I. -O3 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrength-reduce -funroll-loops -ffast-math -c -fPIC -DPIC autotalent.c mayer_fft.c
gcc -nostartfiles -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -lc -lm -lrt -o autotalent.so autotalent.o mayer_fft.o
ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [autotalent.so] Error 1
```

So no .so file is generated but the .o files have been made. Is this by any chance an easy fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OSX has a different form of shared library to Linux. See [Apple's Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/CreatingDynamicLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002073-SW1).

To create a shared library the command is like

```
gcc -dynamiclib  autotalent.c mayer_fft.c -current_version 1.0 -compatibility_version 1.0 -fvisibility=hidden -o lib autotalent.A.dylib
```

Comment: that raises the error "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: autotalent.A.dylib: No such file or directory".